# How to modify Publish metabox?

Tags: metabox, publish, customization

I'm trying to remove "Pending Review" (Status) and "Password protected" (Visibility) options from Publish metabox. Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21487/can-custom-taxonomies-be-displayed-inside-of-a-custom-meta-box) Question and my answer, which is quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

I always do it with Frank Bültge's [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/)

- in Global Options, you'll find Your Own Options
- in the left column you put any name for your reference
- in the right column you put the ID or Classes you want to hide
- if I'm not mistaken, you'd want to hide this `#visibility.misc-pub-section,.misc-pub-section.curtime.misc-pub-section-last`

Here's a [reference list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At1Lam3pVrdMdGxMTlVhZzVmZDNidWgtVHdHUnA0aHc) of mine with examples and a screenshot... you can go pretty wild and hide a whole bunch of stuff, and select what to hide according to user roles, it's just a matter of using Firebug or any Inspector and you'll end up with a minimalist admin.